# Problem to read .dat files in Panda in a loop from Folder

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, for-loop

I have a strange problem. In my folder i have .dat data with CO2 values from a CO2 sensor in the laboratory. Data from experiment 4,5,6,7,8 with names CO2_4.dat,CO2_5.dat,CO2_6.dat,CO2_7.dat,CO2_8.dat
I know how to read them manually. For example for reading CO2_4 this works :

```
dfCO2_4_manual = pd.read_csv(r'C:\data\CO2\co2_4.dat', sep=";", encoding= 'unicode_escape', header = 0, skiprows=[0], usecols=[0,1,2,4], names =["ts","t","co2_4", "p"])
display(dfCO2_4_manual)
```

which gives me a dataframe with the correct values:

[image]

every minute one value

But if i want to loop over my folder and read them all with this technique ("which work for other CSV files from the laboratory") which is safing the dataframes in a dictionary:

```
exp_list =[4,5,6,7,8]                                           # list with number of each experiment

path_CO2 = r'C:\data\CO2'             
CO2_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path_CO2, "*.dat"))           
CO2_dict = {}

for f, i in zip(offline_files, exp_list):                         
    CO2_dict["CO2_{0}".format(i)] = pd.read_csv(f, sep=";", encoding= 'unicode_escape', header = 0, skiprows=[0], usecols=[0,1,2,4], names =["ts","t","CO2_{0}".format(i), "p"])
display(CO2_dict["CO2_4"])
```

gives me a dataframe with many skipped and completely wrong values.

[image]

If i open the CO2_4.dat data with text editor it looks like this:

[image]

Does someone know what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how to help exactly given we don't have access to your files, however, is this line

```
for f, i in zip(offline_files, exp_list):
```

correct? Where is offline_files defined? It's not in the code you have provided. Also, are you wanting to analyze each df separately? Is that why you are storing them in a dictionary?

As an alternative you can store each df in a list and concatenate them. You can then group and apply analyses to them that way.

```
df_hold_list = []
for f, i in zip(CO2_files, exp_list): #changed file list name; please verify          
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=";", encoding= 'unicode_escape', header = 0, skiprows=[0], usecols=[0,1,2,4], names =["ts","t","CO2_{0}".format(i), "p"])
    df['file'] = 'CO2_{0}'.format(i) # add column for sorting/grouping
df_hold_list.append(df)

df_new = pd.concat(df_hold_list, axis=0) # check the axis, should be 0 or 1
```

I can't test the code, but should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Yes im very blind, thank you very much.... i overlooked for a very long time .... Well that was a bad question for the platform, but it helped me at least. Thank you and also good advice with the list :)